# UIButton click through in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I click the `UIButton` in a `UICollectionViewCell`, both the button's `callback` and `collectionView:didSelectCellAtIndexPath` are called. How can I get rid of this and call only the `callback` of the button?

Comment: You need to set target of button in collection view method cell for row at indexpath , if you taking cell programatically otherwise need to set target in CollectionViewCell file.

Comment: @Lei Wei Other option is do not do anything in your collectionView:didSelectCellAtIndexPath method.

Comment: The cell itself is the target of the button and I set a block in collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath to act as the callback.

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya the button and the cell has different responding logic

Comment: Change the target to view controller from the cell. It should work. Can you share some code how you are adding the button target?

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionViewDelegate has method

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

just return NO when you don't need `collectionView:didSelectCellAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

You can follow many approach in that case :

1 - Dont implement `collectionView:didSelectCellAtIndexPath` method in your view controller.
2 - If it is mandatory for you to implement this, give one unique tag to that cell, then check for tag value in `collectionView:didSelectCellAtIndexPath` method and do nothing if tag condition holds true.

Answer (score 0):

**didSelectItemAtIndexPath** method is not a required method in UICollectionViewDelegate. You need to implement the same only when its required.

If its required at your end then To stop the cells from getting selected use **shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath** method in UICollectionViewDelegate and return NO.
Thenceforth you can add the action to button in the cell with your ViewController as target.